# msal.js: acquireTokenSilent does not work with Internet Explorer 11

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, frontend, msal.js

I am working on a project authenticates users with azure active directory. Fetching the user token works fine, I get all user information. But when I try to acquire an access token via acquireTokenSilent, I get the following error:

```
"AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in."
```

It works fine for every other browser.

To add my website to the "IE security zone" as suggeste in this [issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/323#issuecomment-466035718) is not possible unfortunally due to the policy of my company.

Edit: Setting the `storeAuthStateInCookie` as Allen Wu suggested only solved the problem of getting no login token. Unfortunally, I need an access token via acquireTokenSilent to authenticate with my backend. Gaterhing an access token works with every browser but Internet Explorer. Sorry, I hope that cleared the question.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [known issues](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/wiki/Known-issues-on-IE-and-Edge-Browser#update-fix-available-in-msaljs-023), there is a `storeAuthStateInCookie` flag to resolve this issue for login redirect flows in IE.

See this [JS sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-spa#configure-your-javascript-spa):

> set it to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunally, i does not solve the problem of getting an access token, only of getting an login token. I found a issue on Github which describes the problem better https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/323

Answer (score 2):

To Add to Allen's response, That only works if you are using the login redirect flow.  if that doesn't fix your issue and you are using loginpopupflow, then the only workaround available is to get the enterprise to add "https://login.microsoftonline.com" as a trusted site for all employees using a group policy.

Regards,